# Evaluate the Integral: $\int_0^2 \frac{dx}{e^{\pi x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the definite integral: $$\int_0^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^{\pi x}}$$

My attempt:

$u=e^{\pi x}$

$du=\pi e^{\pi x}\ dx$

$\int_0^2 \frac{1}{u}\ dx$

So at this point do I divide $\pi e^{\pi x}$ by dx?

Thus, $\frac{du}{\pi\ e^{\pi x}}=dx$

and $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{\pi\ e^{\pi x}}$

and $\frac{1}{u}\int_0^2\frac{du}{\pi\ e^{\pi x}} $

Find the new values for integral? I have no idea how to do this.

I basically would like to know if my process of solving this problem is correct and how to complete solving the problem.

Comment: Don't do $u$ substitution.  Just write $\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}}$ as $e^{-\pi x}$.  Then you have $\int e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}+ C$

Comment: You don't need to do a $u$ substitution. You should know the antiderivative of $1/e^{\pi x}$

Comment: $e^x+c$ seems to be the anti derivative of $e^x$ .

Comment: Yes and $\frac{e^{ax}}{a} + c$ is the antiderivative of $e^{ax}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do $$ \int_0^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^{\pi x}} = \int_0^2 e^{-\pi x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[-\frac{e^{-\pi x}}{\pi}\right]_0^2 = \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{e^{-2\pi}}{\pi} = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(1 - \frac{1}{e^{2\pi} }\right)$$

This is because we have, for $a\neq 0$: $$\int e^{ax} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{e^{ax}}{a} + c$$

Comment: If $ a \neq 0$...

Comment: @Dmoreno, thanks. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The steps presented are on the correct path, but are slighlty off. Consider
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{e^{a x}} = \int_{0}^{2} e^{-a x} \, dx
\end{align}
let $u = e^{-ax}$ for which $du = -a \, e^{-a x} \, dx$, $x = 0 \to u = 1$, $x = 2 \to u = e^{-2 a}$ and leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{1}^{e^{-2 a}} \frac{du}{(-a)} = - \frac{1}{a} \, \int_{1}^{e^{-2 a}} \, du = - \frac{1}{a} \, \left[ u \right]_{1}^{e^{-2 a}} \\
&= \frac{1 - e^{-2 a}}{a} = \frac{2}{a} \, e^{- a} \, \sinh(a).
\end{align}
When $a = \pi$ the desired integral value is obtained.

Answer (score -1):

note that in $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{\pi\ e^{\pi x}}$ we can substitute $\pi\ e^{\pi x}$ with $\pi u$. Thus $$\int_0^2 \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{\pi\ e^{\pi x}} = \int_0^2 \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{\pi\ u} = \int_0^2 \frac{du}{\pi u^2} = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[ -\frac{1}{u} \right]^{u=2}_{u=0}$$.
However you forgot to change the range of the integral with the substitution with $u=e^{\pi x}$ thus this does not work. $x=0 \rightarrow u= 1$ and $x=2 \rightarrow u= e^{2 \pi}$. You have to put these in so we get:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left[ -\frac{1}{u} \right]^{u=e^{2 \pi}}_{u=1} = \frac{-1}{\pi e^{2 \pi}} +\frac{1}{\pi}  $$

Comment: Are you sure about those limits?

Comment: I am merely pointing out how to work the last portion. The limits of the integral are not correct, this is what I was trying to say in the last part.

Comment: It would be more useful to the OP if you could show what the new limits should be.

Comment: Edited it now so new limits are shown.

Comment: Good job...! :-)